# jQuery: remember data-toggle tab when pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `nav-tabs`:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class=""><a href="#not-permitted" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false"> 승인 대기 </a></li>
    <li><a href="#ready-to-pay" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true"> 결제 대기 </a></li>
    <li><a href="#paid" data-toggle="tab"> 결제 완료 </a></li>
    <li><a href="#canceled" data-toggle="tab"> 취소 완료 </a></li>
</ul>
```

and each tab has pagination.

This is my `jQuery` code for remembering last tab when pagination:

**test.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        // Execution1
        localStorage.setItem('lastTab', $(this).attr('href'));
    });

    // Execution2
    var lastTab = localStorage.getItem('lastTab');
    if (lastTab) {
        $('[href="' + lastTab + '"]').tab('show');
    } else {
        $('[href="#not-permitted"]').tab('show');
    }
});
```

This works bad because `Execution2` part should be executed after `Execution1` executed, but it doesn't work sometime because event function is asynchronous.

So I changed the code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        localStorage.setItem('lastTab', $(this).attr('href'));
        // go to the latest tab, if it exists:
        var lastTab = localStorage.getItem('lastTab');
        if (lastTab) {
            $('[href="' + lastTab + '"]').tab('show');
        } else {
            $('[href="#not-permitted"]').tab('show');
        }
    });
});
```

Seems good but it doesn't show any tab when page is loaded(or refresh) because `shown.bs.tab` event does not occur when page is firstly loaded.

Could you give me some idea, please?

**Edit**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').trigger("click") 
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        localStorage.setItem('lastTab', $(this).attr('href'));
        // go to the latest tab, if it exists:
        var lastTab = localStorage.getItem('lastTab');
        if (lastTab) {
            $('[href="' + lastTab + '"]').tab('show');
        } else {
            $('[href="#not-permitted"]').tab('show');
        }
    });
});
```

also doesn't work... it click all tabs one by one..continuously..

Comment: Then invoke it on `window.onload` or `$(document).ready` event!

Comment: Sorry, but could you give me some example, please?

Comment: Just google those things I have mentioned! Will help you in long run :)

Comment: What is 'it' in 'Then invoke it'?

Comment: Invoke `Execution2`

Comment: just pull a trigger

Comment: Still cannot understand..

Comment: $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').trigger("click") perhaps on document.ready

Comment: @Deep Thanks but it doesn't work.... T _ T

Comment: Where did you put this line of code, it should have worked?

Comment: @Deep I added a code in a post